# Get all records from azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Using this code block

```
try
{
    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
    CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

    CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("serviceAlerts");

    TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<ServiceAlertsEntity>("ServiceAlerts", "b9ccd839-dd99-4358-b90f-46781b87f933");

    TableResult query = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

    if (query.Result != null)
    {
        outline = outline + ((ServiceAlertsEntity) query.Result).alertMessage + " * ";
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Alerts");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

I am able to retrieve the single record with the partition and rowkey mentioned in the retrieve.

Is there a way I can get all the records that are stored in the partition of ServiceAlerts?

I have tried a wildcard (*) for the second parameter

```
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<ServiceAlertsEntity>(
      "ServiceAlerts","b9ccd839-dd99-4358-b90f-46781b87f933");
```

but it does not return anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify a TableQuery, this will give you all entities or you can specify a `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` to filter the rows.

```
TableQuery<ServiceAlertsEntity> query = new TableQuery<ServiceAlertsEntity>();

foreach (ServiceAlertsEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
                        entity.Field1, entity.Field2);
}
```

Comment: table.ExecuteQuery returns an IEnumerable which means it will bring all the data across multiple partition server. This approach is not good

Comment: And what if 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' ?

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant. This is for the old/retired Azure Table SDK

Answer (score 20):

If you need further control over the records being returned, you can use `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` to retrieve data a page (around 1,000 records) at a time.

```
    var alerts = new List<ServiceAlertsEntity>();

    var query = new TableQuery<ServiceAlertsEntity>();
    TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        var page = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
        continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
        alerts.AddRange(page.Results);
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);
```

Or if you need to restrict your results, e.g. by Partition Key, you can add a filter condition by adding a `Where` clause to the query in the above code.

```
    var pk = "abc";
    var filterPk = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
        nameof(ServiceAlertsEntity.PartitionKey),
        QueryComparisons.Equal, pk);

    var query = new TableQuery<ServiceAlertsEntity>().Where(filterPk);
```

[MS Azure reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#retrieve-entities-in-pages-asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong class. Use TableQuery to retrieve multiple results.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same process using generic class. Using function app i have achieved this. please find the following codes.
First i have created a function app **MyEventhubTrigger.cs**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using AzureMonitorFunctions.WebHook;



namespace MyFunctions
{
    public static class MyEventhubTrigger
    {               

        [FunctionName("MyEventhubTrigger")]       
       public static async void Run([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "devicestatuscg")] string myEventHubMessage, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, Int64 sequenceNumber, string offset, ILogger log)
        {           
            log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {myEventHubMessage}");
            try
            {                 
                StorageTableOperation<StorageTable> tableObj = new StorageTableOperation<StorageTable>("EventhubMessages");
                Eventhubstorage Eventhubdada = tableObj.GetTableData("Eventhub", "DeviceStatus");
                if (Eventhubdada.EnqueuedTime < enqueuedTimeUtc)
                {                    
                        Eventhubdada.EnqueuedTime = enqueuedTimeUtc;
                        Eventhubdada.Offset = offset;
                        Eventhubdada.Sequence = sequenceNumber;
                        await tableObj.UpdateTableData("Eventhub", "DeviceStatus", Eventhubdada);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i have create table storage in azure storage account. And add the same field in a property file. which is **StorageTable.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace MyFunctions
{
    public class StorageTable : TableEntity
    {
        public StorageTable()
        {
        }
        public StorageTable(string PKey, string RKey)
        {
            PartitionKey = PKey;
            RowKey = RKey;
        }

        public DateTime EnqueuedTime { get; set; }
        public Int64 Sequence { get; set; }
        public string Offset { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I have created a class which can take any TableEntity property class and do the following operation Get/insert/Update. Find the following code for **StorageTableOperation.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MyFunctions
{
    public class StorageTableOperation<T> where T : ITableEntity
    {       
        internal CloudTable cloudTable;        

        public StorageTableOperation(string tableName)
        {
            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            cloudTable = client.GetTableReference(tableName);
        }
        public T GetTableData(string PartitionKey,string RowKey)
        {           
            TableOperation retOp = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(PartitionKey, RowKey);
            TableResult result = cloudTable.Execute(retOp);
            T tableData = (T)result.Result;


            return tableData;
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateTableData(string PartitionKey, string RowKey, T tableData)
        {
            try
            {               
                TableOperation operation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(tableData);
                TableResult tableResult = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(operation);
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the newer Azure.Data.Tables SDK this is now much shorter, especially when using the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) nuget package. With that you can simplay write:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns all rows in a given Partition
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Implementation of ITableEntity</typeparam>
/// <param name="tableClient">The authenticated TableClient</param>
/// <param name="partitionKey">The PartitionKey</param>
/// <returns>List of all entities with specified PartitionKey</returns>
public static async Task<IList<T>> GetAllEntitiesByPartitionKeyAsync<T>(this TableClient tableClient, string partitionKey) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
{
    return await tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(x => x.PartitionKey == partitionKey, maxPerPage: 1000).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Note: by requesting 1000 rows at once (max) the total amount of requests can be drastically reduced.

[Source](https://github.com/ThomasPe/Azure.Data.Tables-Extensions/blob/main/src/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.Extensions/Extensions.cs#L48)

Comment: This is the correct and current answer. Thanks @Thomas

Comment: @MauricioAviles you answer is working fine but I have 5000 data in my parition key how to get all of the data because if I specify 1000 as max limit it will give only 1000 data is there any option to get rest of the data using some feature like continution token

Comment: the .ToListAsync() will download all available rows in blocks of 1000. if you have 5000 rows it should download all of them as you can see here https://github.com/ThomasPe/Azure.Data.Tables-Extensions/blob/main/src/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.Extensions.Tests/ExtensionTests.cs#L89