# Retrieving data from azure storage table using azure functions

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-functions

I am trying to retrieve specific column data from the Azure storage table using azure functions. I'm using the table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve()) method but I don't know if what I'm doing is right.

```
static async Task<TableResult>  GetAllMessages(CloudTable table, String InvocationName)
{

    TableResult x = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve(InvocationName,"1" ));    
    return x;
}

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route =null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger log)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("models");
    var x = await GetAllMessages(table, "InvocationName");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve this data based on some condition or fetch the entire column?

Comment: [`TableOperation.Retrieve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.retrieve?view=azure-dotnet) retrieves a single row from a table based on `PartitionKey, RowKey`, and the overloads with `selectedColumns` allows you to project only specific columns out. If you want to retrieve all rows from a table, or from a partition, then you will need a [TableQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38748896/314291)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turned out that I neede to create a class that extends TableEntity and include my table columns in that class

```
class model : TableEntity{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString(){
     return  " " + Name;
    }
}
static async Task<TableResult>  GetAllMessages(CloudTable table, String InvocationName)
{

    TableResult x = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve(InvocationName,"1" ));    
    return x;
}

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route =null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger log)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("models");
    var x = await GetAllMessages(table, "InvocationName");
    string url = ((model)x.Result).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure Function supports the Azure Table bindings. You could use it to read or insert table. You could get details from here:[Azure Table storage bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table).

And if you want to read multiple table rows, you need use `IQueryable` , and here is the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---c-example---iqueryable) in the official doc.

```
public class TableStorage
{
    public class MyPoco : TableEntity
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [FunctionName("TableInput")]
    public static void TableInput(
        [QueueTrigger("table-items")] string input, 
        [Table("MyTable", "MyPartition")] IQueryable<MyPoco> pocos, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        foreach (MyPoco poco in pocos)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"PK={poco.PartitionKey}, RK={poco.RowKey}, Text={poco.Text}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that IQueryable is not avaliable for V2 runtime functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---usage

Comment: @george please note that v2 doesnt support iqueryable