# How to fetch all the records from azure table storage through azure function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to fetch the records from azure table storage one by one and read them. I have gone through a couple of similar questions in "stack overflow" and created the below code. But couldn't able to read the data from Azure table storage.
I want to read the data one by one and assign them to the variable "Table" and "Type" (local variable inside the function).
Could anyone help me with this?

**Azure Table Data**

[image]

**Class**

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace DataLoad

{
public class AzureTableEntity : TableEntity
{
public AzureTableEntity(string Table)
{
    this.PartitionKey = Table;
    this.RowKey = Table;
}

public AzureTableEntity()
{
}

public string Table { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }

}
}
```

**Function**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace DataLoad
{
public static class DeltaDataload
{
    [FunctionName("DeltaDataload")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 05 17 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {

        string Table="";
        string Type="";
        const string StorageAccountName = "";
        const string StorageAccountKey = "";
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
        new StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey), true);
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        CloudTable tableReference2 = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("DataTable");
        TableOperation operation2 = TableOperation.Retrieve<AzureTableEntity>(nameof(DataLoad), Entity.ToString(),(List<string>)null);
        var tableResult = tableReference2.ExecuteAsync(operation2);
        string abc = tableResult.Result.ToString();
        TableContinuationToken token = null;

        var entities = new List<AzureTableEntity>();
       
            var queryResult = tableReference2.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<AzureTableEntity>(), token);
            entities.AddRange(queryResult.Result);
        


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am following this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=in-process,storage-extension&pivots=programming-language-csharp) and the below example shows a [C# function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) that reads a single table row. The function will be triggered for each message sent to the queue.
The message metadata, which is the message string, is bound to the row key via the row key value `queueTrigger`.

```
public class TableStorage
{
    public class MyPoco
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [FunctionName("TableInput")]
    public static void TableInput(
        [QueueTrigger("table-items")] string input, 
        [Table("MyTable", "MyPartition", "{queueTrigger}")] MyPoco poco, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"PK={poco.PartitionKey}, RK={poco.RowKey}, Text={poco.Text}");
    }
}
```

To read the table using the Azure Storage SDK, use the `CloudTable` method argument. Here's an example of a querying an Azure Functions log table function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionAppCloudTable2
{
    public class LogEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public string OriginalName { get; set; }
    }
    public static class CloudTableDemo
    {
        [FunctionName("CloudTableDemo")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, 
            [Table("AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon")] CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            TableQuery<LogEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<LogEntity>().Where(
                TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, 
                        "FD2"),
                    TableOperators.And,
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, 
                        "t")));

            // Execute the query and loop through the results
            foreach (LogEntity entity in 
                await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(rangeQuery, null))
            {
                log.LogInformation(
                    $"{entity.PartitionKey}\t{entity.RowKey}\t{entity.Timestamp}\t{entity.OriginalName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer [Get started with Azure Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet) to know how to use CloudTable.
If you get an error message when trying to bind to `CloudTable`, ensure that you have a reference to   [the correct Storage SDK version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#azure-storage-sdk-version-in-functions-1x).

Also, you can refer to this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748426/get-all-records-from-azure-table-storage) for more information.